# EmberJs: 404 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/my-app.css

Tags: javascript, ember.js, semantic-ui

I will preface this by saying I am very new to using Ember (1 week) and JS frameworks in general but have been developing .Net WebAPIs and building by own JS front ends for a few years.

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find any clues on how to debug this issue. I recently integrated Semantic-UI into my app and was able to use it fine for a little while. However, this morning my application started throwing a 404 when trying to access the bundled stylesheet.

I've tried reverting to previous versions and I've even run `ember init` neither of which resolved the issue.

Currently, I am trying to just create a new app, but am facing issues on that front as well...

```
$ ember version
version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: win32 x64
```

bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.7",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.13.8",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.9",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.1",
    "qunit": "~1.18.0",
    "semantic-ui": "~2.0.8"
  }
```

EDIT: 
Below is my ember-cli-build.js file:

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        lessOptions: {
            paths: [
              'bower_components/semantic-ui'
            ]
        }
    });

  return app.toTree();
};
```

I can't even create a new ember project in a new directory now to validate this because I keep getting the following error:

```
EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\debug\2.2.0\package\package.json'
Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\debug\2.2.0\package\package.json'
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: You might need to load some files from the module in `ember-cli-build.js` (formerly `Brocfile.js`). For more information see 'Asset Compilation' section of the Ember CLI documentation: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation

Comment: I've updated the above post to show my `ember-cli-build.js` file. Also, I have run `ember install ember-cli-less` which has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Ember CLI in combination with Windows, perhaps you should report this as a bug?